# Unable to find EVP_sha256 during compilation

Tags: c++, openssl, hmac

I have to generate a hash of 256 bit length for a given input. I am making use of ‘EVP_sha256’.

> error: ‘EVP_sha256’ was not declared in this scope

Below is my code ---

```
HMAC_Init_ex(&hmac, key, keyLength, EVP_sha256(), NULL);
```

I have included openssl/evp.h in my cpp file.

Using openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013.

Any pointers?

---

Program below

File name : Generatehash.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>
#include <openssl/hmac.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;
int KEY_SIZE = 256;
int AES_BLOCK_SIZE = 16;
int IV_SIZE = 16;

void hmac(unsigned char* key, int keyLength, string msg, unsigned char*         hash)
{

  HMAC_CTX hmac;
  HMAC_CTX_init(&hmac);
  HMAC_Init_ex(&hmac, key, keyLength, EVP_sha256(), NULL);
  if(HMAC_Update(&hmac, ( unsigned char* )&msg[0], msg.length()))
    cout<<"Update success"<<endl;

  unsigned int len = 0;
  if(HMAC_Final(&hmac, hash, &len))
    cout<<"Final success"<<endl;
  HMAC_CTX_cleanup(&hmac);
}

int GenerateHashValue(unsigned char* encryptionKey, int keyLength, string     uri, unsigned char* iv)
{
  unsigned char hashBuffer[32] = {'\0'};
  hmac(encryptionKey, keyLength, uri, hashBuffer);
}

int main()
{
  std::cout<<"TEST START =====>>\n";

  string key = "Jwe9#z+IND.niSNDJwe9#z+IND.niSND";

  string strData = "www.format@imminent.com";

  unsigned char iv[16] = {'\0'};

  GenerateHashValue((unsigned char*)key.c_str(),key.length(),strData, iv);

  std::cout<<"TEST END =====>>\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Command used for compilation

g++ Generatehash.cpp -lssl -lcrypto

Comment: Please state where OpenSSL headers are located, and state what your command is to compile your program.

Comment: I have attached code above. Did some debugging myself. File present in /usr/include/openssl/evp.h. Also *EVP_sha256() is under flag OPENSSL_NO_SHA256 in the above mentioned header file. I feel, the error may be due to this flag being set in the env in which i am compiling. I am not sure how or where this is set.